# RailsAdmin: polymorphic has_one association rendering in edit and list views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, has-one, rails-admin

So I'm having the following model structure

```
class Product < AR
  belongs_to :buyable, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :product
end

class Stone < AR
  has_one :product, :as => :buyable, :inverse_of => :buyable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and this RailsAdmin configuration:

```
config.included_models = [Product, Stone]

config.model Stone do
  edit do
    field :product
    field :rock
  end
end
```

When I'm creating a new Stone-Record, it's working, but the Product fields are collapsed. But since every stone has to have all product fields filled out (according validations are in the model) I want them to always be not-collapsed. I tried adding `visible` to the configuration, but that's not working...

Also when I want to have the name attribute to be displayed in the Stone list view of RailsAdmin, it's not working by supplying `field :product` in the configuration... I couldn't get my head around it, not even after reading the whole wiki and searching on Google like a maniac...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option for that:

```
active true
```

About your second question, you may want to use the `configure` verb instead of `field`.

`configure` won't interfere with the flow of default fields like `field` does.

RailsAdmin has a project wiki. Whenever you find something that's not documented, you can add it there.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by interfere with the flow?

Comment: @Vapire: Freeze fields' order.
Use :field when you want to set a list of fields in specific ordering, use :configure when you want to keep default fields with their native (ORM-bound) ordering.

Comment: Thanks, I set my has_one field to `active` and it is showing up now. But the nested fields aren't respecting the RA config options I've set for the model. Specifically, Rating a polymorphic `belongs_to`, and the ratable_type field is showing in the nested fields. Any trick to make those hidden, as I've specified in the RA config for the `Rating` model? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, to get the product displayed in the list view, you would need:

```
config.model Stone do
  list do
    field :product
    field :rock
  end
end
```

And I don't know the answer to your **real** question. I don't think there is a configuration for the collapsibility of nested fields. I can't find anything in the documentation that mentions this. Perhaps this question should be asked in the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/rails_admin)?